# How to call C++ object method if exists, else call a global function

Tags: c++

I have an `ASSERT` macro that works as you'd expect `assert` to work except it invokes my own global function (say `myAssertFunc()`) if the assert fails, which does some custom things before aborting the program.  Something like:

```
#define ASSERT(_c) if (!(_c)) myAssertFunc(#_c)
void myAssertFunc(const char* condition);
```

(various details left out of course but you get the idea).

What I'd like to be able to do is define a method `myAssertFunc()` in various classes, so that when the `ASSERT()` macro is evaluated in the context of objects of that class the local method is invoked.  So in some classes I would say:

```
class MyClass {
    void myAssertFunc(const char* condition);
    void run() { ASSERT(isOK); doStuff(); }
};
```

now when I invoke `ASSERT()` in a member method of that class, `MyClass::myAssertFunc()` will be called instead of the global function.

Unfortunately, I stumbled across a bizarre scoping rule in C++; if you have an inner class then symbols are matched in the outer class first.  So if I have:

```
class MyClass {
    void myAssertFunc(const char* condition);
    void run() { ASSERT(isOK); doStuff(); }
    class InnerClass {
        void doIt() { ASSERT(canDo); moreStuff(); }
    };
};
```

everything breaks, because when `myAssertFunc` is evaluated in the inner class `doIt()` function it inexplicably resolves to `MyClass::myAssertFunc()` rather than the global `::myAssertFunc()`.  Obviously that's completely invalid, because I'm in a different class here and I can't run that method anyway!  I can't explain why that would be useful.

In any event, can anyone think of a way I could do this?

If I had a way to compile-time detect whether or not my current class has a method I could do this:

```
#define ASSERT(_c) if (!(_c)) if (has_method(myAssertFunc)) myAssertFunc(#_c) else ::myAssertFunc(#_c)
```

I found various solutions to the problem "how can I tell if class XYZ has method abc()" but they all require you to know the name of class XYZ which I don't: I just want "the class of the current object".  Oh and of course, `ASSERT()` needs to be callable in static methods.  I'm beginning to think this is impossible, but maybe someone will prove me wrong!  I'm happy if the solution is limited to relatively newer GCC versions (GCC 6.x and above would be ideal)... I'm OK if this can't be done with Visual Studio or older clang/llvm.

Also anyone who can provide a reasonable justification for C++'s current name scoping rules WRT inner classes, I'm curious about that.

Comment: `inexplicably`? Very well defined behavior, and usually the one most people want. Inner scope always includes outer scope names.

Comment: "Most people want"?  How can you use it?  If method a() exists in outer scope, I can't call method a() from my inner scope... `this` is the wrong type.  I have to have an object of the outer class, in which case I'm running `o->a()` anyway.  So what's the point of having `a()` expand to the outer class scope?  It will always just be an error.

Comment: Nope. You can access static members or types, for example.

Comment: @MadScientist This is caused by the unqualified name lookup rule, if a name is found, then name lookup stops. It's a fundamental rule, hard to modify. Another annoying example is function name from private inheritance.

Comment: If you always use that macro in non static member functions, you could do something along those lines: https://ideone.com/kFe2UN

Comment: Sure but it works ONLY for static things.  For non-static you must get an error.  I agree that there's some value in having the same rule for all things, even if it doesn't make any sense for some of them.  It is annoying though.

Comment: @Caninonos nice.  Unfortunately it's a big ask to have people use different ASSERT() macros for static methods vs. object methods.  It's too bad C++ doesn't have some compile-time way of asking "is this symbol valid in this context?" for all contexts.